# Do spontaneous nuclear decay and a reactor-decay ultimately involve same energy release?

Tags: nuclear-physics

I want to compare two scenarios here. A particular nuclide undergoes spontaneous nuclear decay and release energy in form of emitted particles, their kinetic energies and radiations. In another case, the same nuclide is forced to undergo fission in a reactor, which also release energy. Can we expect these energies to be equal, although the rate at which it is released is drastically different? (Spontaneous decay is obviously slow considering the half-life)

Comment: How are you 'forcing' the reaction? Spontaneous fission is not the same as neutron-induced fission. Low energy vs high energy neutron-induced fission can be different.

Answer (score 0):

The energy released in spontaneous fission is generally lower than that obtained by induced fission  .
As always, the energy released is equal to the mass destroyed times c2, so we must find the difference in mass between the fissile parent  and the fission products.